# How to select a column by its position and use it in a formula with other column in Databricks Spark Scala?

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am using Scala on Databricks. Let's say I have a dataframe like the following:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("Alex", 4.0, 3.2, 3.0),
  ("John", 2.0, 4.2, 1.2),
  ("Alice", 1.0, 5.0, 3.5),
  ("Mark", 3.0, 3.5, 0.5),
).toDF("Name", "Test A", "Test B", "Test C")
```

which gives me:

| Name | Test A | Test B | Test C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | 4.0 | 3.2 | 3.0 |
| John | 2.0 | 4.2 | 1.2 |
| Alice | 1.0 | 5.0 | 3.5 |
| Mark | 3.0 | 3.5 | 0.5 |

I want to create a new column that has the result of the division of column `Test B` by column `Test C`. However, I need to select `Test B` not by its name, but by its position.

I am trying to do the following:

```
df
.withColumn("ratio B/C", df[3]/$"Test C")
```

or

```
df
.withColumn("ratio B/C", df.columns[3]/$"Test C")
```

I was expecting `df[3]` or `df.columns[3]` to select the `Test B` column, but I always get errors like: `<console>:6: error: identifier expected but integer literal found.`

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can `map` over your `DataFrame` and then access the `Row`'s elements by their positions:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import spark.implicits._

val columnNames = Seq("Name", "Test A", "Test B", "Test C")
val df = Seq(
  ("Alex", 4.0, 3.2, 3.0),
  ("John", 2.0, 4.2, 1.2),
  ("Alice", 1.0, 5.0, 3.5),
  ("Mark", 3.0, 3.5, 0.5)
).toDF(columnNames: _*)

val output = df.map{
  row => {
    // Dividing the numbers by position
    val division = row.getDouble(3) / row.getDouble(2)
    // Creating a new row with an extra element: division
    (row.getString(0), row.getDouble(1), row.getDouble(2), row.getDouble(3), division)
  }
}.toDF(columnNames :+ "division": _*)

output.show                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
+-----+------+------+------+-------------------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
| Name|Test A|Test B|Test C|           division|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
+-----+------+------+------+-------------------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
| Alex|   4.0|   3.2|   3.0|             0.9375|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
| John|   2.0|   4.2|   1.2| 0.2857142857142857|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
|Alice|   1.0|   5.0|   3.5|                0.7|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
| Mark|   3.0|   3.5|   0.5|0.14285714285714285|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
+-----+------+------+------+-------------------+
```

Hope this helps!